# Data Copy from Azure blob to S3 andn Synapse to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

There is a requirement to copy from Azure Blob to S3 for 10TB data and also from Synpase to Redshift for 10TB of data.

What is the best way to achieve these 2 migrations?

Comment: Synpase? more details plz?  Migration to Redshift usually means migration to S3 and then load data. 10TB - depending on your network you may (or not) find the aws snowball service feasible too

Comment: Azure Synapse Analytics. The client is okay to migrate slowly and not at once. So maybe snowball is not an option for them.

Answer (score 0):

For the Redshift - you could export Azure Synapse Analytics to a a blob storage in a [compatible format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html#r_COPY-syntax-overview-data-format) ideally compressed and then copy the data to S3. It is pretty straightforward to import data from S3 to Redshift.

You may need a VM instance to load read from Azure Storage and put into AWS S3 (doesn't matter where). The simplest option seems to be using the default CLI (Azure and AWS) to read the content to the migration instance and write to to the target bucket. However me personally - I'd maybe create an application writing down checkpoints, if the migration process interrupts for any reason, the migration process wouldn't need to start from the scratch.

There are a few options you may "tweak" based on the files to move, if there are many small files or less large files, from which region to move where, ....

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-upload-large-files/

As well you may consider using the [AWS S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html), may or may not help too.

Please note every larger cloud provider has some [outbound data egress cost](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/), for 10TB it may be considerable cost

Comment: The issue is the client is very sensitive and might not want data to be stored temporarily stored in any VM. Also, schema conversion also has to happen between synapse and redshift.

Comment: @Jagaran in theory - you can write an application directly reading and writing data as a stream without storing anything. However - it will take more time and money and the client then needs to trust a 3rd party app. I'd suggest using the tools at hand while having options to secure the temporary VM storage.  Schema conv. is different topic with multiple option, let's just state the simplest - when exporting and importing, it is possible to use "external tables" with required schema